# zsh auto completion in home dir 

Tags: zsh, ubuntu-11.04, zsh-completion

I used for years in openSuSE the:

```
#compdef w
 _files -W ~/work -/
```

function to auto-complete the directory names in my ~/work dir.

It does not work in Ubuntu zsh -v 4.3.11, when I hit `TAB` after `w` I got directories from my home directory.

What's different in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I found [cdpath variable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_13.html). I added in my config file

```
cdpath=( /usr ~ ~/work )
```

and it works :) Just `cd somechar` <kbd>Tab</kbd>. No more `compdef` functions.